# Rake Aborted - SystemStackError

Tags: ruby, macos, ruby-on-rails-4, macos-catalina

I am trying to setup a rails project in **MacBook -  Catalina 10.15.6**, But am failing to run it successfully. All bundle things done and then when am hitting command

```
bundle exec rake db:create
```

I get the following error

```
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Here is system details

```
OS: Mac Catalina
Ruby - 2.1.3
Rails - 4.2.0
```

I cant update ruby version too. So any suggestion will be a great help.

Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/ruby/rake/issues/41
seems like an old bug, what rake version you use?

Comment: Post your `config/database.yml` stripped of any credentials, hostnames, and IP addresses. Also, state in what environment you are intending to create the database. If there is a stack trace available then please include it.

Comment: Rake version is 13.0.1

Comment: `development:
  adapter: mysql2
  username: root
  password: 123456
  database: dev
  host: localhost`